# оператор присваивания,(С++)

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня проблема с прокси классом, точнее с оператором присваивания.

```
template<class Key, class Mapped_Type, class Compare = std::less<Key>>
struct PersistentMapProxy
{
    PersistentMap<Key, Mapped_Type, Compare> & parent;
    Key key;
    Mapped_Type value;
    //konstruktor
    PersistentMapProxy(PersistentMap<Key, Mapped_Type, Compare> & parent, Key key)
        : parent(parent), key(key),value((*parent.find(key)).second)
    {

    }

    const Mapped_Type& operator = (const Mapped_Type& value_) const
    {
        value = value_;
        parent.insert(std::make_pair(key, value_));
        return value;
    }
};
```

**UPD.**
Пример контейнера

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct PersistentMap
{
    // ...

    typedef PersistentMapProxy<T1, T2> Proxy;

    Proxy operator[] (T1 key)
    {
        return Proxy(*this, key);
    }

    void assign(T1 key, const T2& value){ /*...*/ }

    // ...
};
```

Не могли  бы вы подсказать(посоветовать)
как в данном случае в операторе:

`const Mapped_Type& operator = (const Mapped_Type& value_) const`

провести копирование значений:

`value = value_;`
если нам заранее не известно что за тип `value`.

щас оно ругается:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  C2678   binary '=': no
>   operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const
>   std::basic_string,std::allocator>'
>   (or there is no acceptable conversion)

**UPD.**
Для полного объяснения, контейнер должен поддерживать данные функции.

```
   using pm2_t = lib::PersistentMap<int, int>;
   pm2_t myMap("Test1");
   myMap[2] = 20;
   int c = 30;
   modify(c);
   modify(myMap[2]);//  тут значение myMap[2] увеличивается на 5. myMap[2]=20+5
   int a = myMap[1];
   int b = myMap[2];
   assert(b == 25);
```

потому и используется прокси класс в такой конструкции.

**UPD.**

Я должен уточнить, что `value` не храниться в карте, оно сразу записывается в файл. В карте только ключи, по которым потом находятся их файлы, и изымаются из файлов значения.

Comment: думаю надо перед `operator=` добавить `Mapped_Type::`  
чтобы было `Mapped_Type::operator=`

Comment: `mapped_type` это может быть инт или стриг и тд, добавление `Mapped_Type::` ничего не дало

Comment: а `const` перед функцией если убрать? Я если честно в `c++` не очень, но конструкция кажется странной

Comment: тоже не помогает, то что перед конструкцией говорит нам, мы хотим вернуть константу. Это стандартная конструкция assigment operator

Comment: Сформулируйте точно вопрос. Я так понимаю должно быть что-то вроде: `SomeClass a,b; a = b; //И тут в parent a добавляется ключ значение на класс b ?`
И какая строка ругается? И почему присваиваются константы?

Comment: В с++ есть такая вещь как Шаблонные классы, это классы которые работают с любыми переменными любых типов, даже пользовательских. У меня имеется шаблонный контейнер, и прокси класс к нему. Мне нужно чтобы, при условии мне мне не известен класс `mapped_type`, `value`  прокси класса приравнять к `value_` данном нам при операции присваивания.

Comment: Проблема в данном случае заключается в том, что `Mapped_Type` является константным типом и, соответственно, `value` - константный объект. Поэтому ответ на исходный вопрос - никак нельзя. В общем случае невозможно использовать константный объект в левой части присваивания. Тут надо начинать с того, что именно вы пытаетесь сделать.

Comment: А если сделать указатель? `Mapped_Type ` что нужно изменить, дабы получить желаемый результат?

Comment: Ох уж эти перегрузки операторов. Ну создайте пока функцию присваивания, попозже вам ответят. Мне во тоже интересно в чем проблема

Comment: у вас в конце функции перегрузки оператора присваивания стоит спецификатор const который предполагает, что вы не будете менять члены класса, а внутри этой функции меняете значения члена **value**, естественно вы ругань компилятора получите

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось проще чем я думал.
маппед тайп я сделал указателем.
`Mapped_Type *value;`
и в копи конструкторе просто изменил значение указателя.

```
const Mapped_Type& operator = (const Mapped_Type& value_)   const
{
    *value = value_;
    parent.insert(std::make_pair(key, value_));
    return *value;
}
```

Comment: Неправильно вы сделали. Указатель-то куда у вас указывает? На одну из ячеек перманентной карты. А вы ее меняете тихой сапой теперь...